# Apache Unable to open logs: /Applications/MAMP/Library/${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost, mamp

I am trying to run a project built in Ubuntu with PHP on fat-free framework. I am using MAMP on macOS Yosemite 10.10.1.

I imported a database successfully through phpmyadmin & following [these instructions](http://foundationphp.com/tutorials/vhosts_mamp.php).  My *httpd-vhosts.conf* file looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs"

    <Directory "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes 
        AllowOverride All 
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>    

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug 

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined    
</VirtualHost>
```

The project files are located at the "htdocs" web root folder in */Applications/MAMP/htdocs*. Note that when I am trying to run it in this form the Apache server throws error, it does not run. When I comment the `ErrorLog` section the Apache server runs properly but all I get is a blank page.

The error message in the apache_error.log is:

> No such file or directory: httpd: could not open error log file */Applications/MAMP/Library/${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log*. Unable to open logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your `APACHE_LOG_DIR` variable is not defined.

See [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1639623).  It says that you need to define it in */etc/apache2/envvars*.  I'm not sure exactly where then *envvars* file would be on a Mac, but it should be with all the other apache2 configuration files.

Alternately, you should just use a hardcoded path rather than `${APACHE_LOG_DIR}`.  For example:

```
ErrorLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/error.log
CustomLog /Applications/MAMP/logs/access.log combined
```

Comment: Now it is working as it supposed to be!